# Detection of sawtooth lines

Tags: hypothesis-testing, algorithms

I would like to ask for a piece of advice on the following problem. I have a set of points that can behave as a sawtooth-like function. I would like to develop an algorithm that could verify that the data shows sawtooth-like behavior. The problem is that in some cases the dots can be random, in other case, there can be multiple sawtooth-like functions interleaving.

The following figure shows an example:
[image: Examples of the Data]

The questions are the following:

1. What algorithm can I use to detect sawtooth like behavior vs random dots?
2. How to detect if the data from multiple sawtooth like functions are on the graph?

**Note:** The dots do not strictly form a line. They are distributed along the line.

Comment: Can you provide a definition of sawtooth? Is it "slope of x1 followed by negative slope of x2, repeated at a fixed period?

Comment: In my case, the data is a set of dots, e.g., (0, 0), (1, 0.67), (2, 1.34), (3, 0), etc. The values on Y-axis are integer, X-axis - is a timestamp.

Comment: Right, but that's not really a description of what a sawtooth pattern is. Can you define what that pattern means to you mathematically? For example the pattern I described roughly. You give points in your reply, but why do you call points like that a sawtooth?

Comment: Yes, actually I get this definition from wiki: y = 2(x/A + floor(1/2+x/A)), where A=2^16. However, this function defines exact values, while in my case the values may not strictly lay on this line. Summing up, y increases with the increase of x until it gets max value (2^16), then drops to 0, increases with the same slope as before and so on.